# Pyspark not running the sqlContext in Pycharm

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

I hope someone could help with this problem I am having. I have previously setup a VM in windows using `CENTOS`, with hadoop and spark (all in singlenode) and it was working perfectly.

I am now running a multinode setup with another computer, both running CENTOS standalone. I have installed hadoop successfully and is running on both machines. Then I've installed `spark` with the following setup:

Version : Spark 2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7, with the `.bashrc` file as follows:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7

export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin

export PATH="/home/hadoop/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

I am using anaconda (`python 2.7` version) to install the pyspark packages. I then have the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` files setup as follows:

the slaves file as:

datanode1

(the hostname of the node which i use to conduct the processing on)

and the spark-env.sh file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.3/etc/hadoop

export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=6
```

The idea is that I then connect the spark to PyCharm IDE to do my work on. In Pycharm I have setup the environment variables (`under run -> edit configurations`) as

[image]

```
PYTHON PATH /opt/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib

SPARK_HOME /opt/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
```

I have also setup my python interpreter to point to the anaconda python directory. 
With all this setup I get multiple errors as output when I call either a spark `SQLContext` or `SparkSession.Builder`, for example:

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)
```

or

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("PythonTutPrac").config("spark.executor.memory","2gb").getOrCreate()
```

The ERROR:

> File "/home/hadoop/Desktop/PythonPrac/CollaborativeFiltering.py", line
>   72, in 
>       .config("spark.executor.memory", "2gb") \   File "/opt/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py",
>   line 183, in getOrCreate
>       session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)   File
>   "/home/hadoop/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1160, in **call**
>       answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   File "/opt/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 79, in deco
>       raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKaNp.png), stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while
>   instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionStateBuilder':"
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by > Process finished with exit code 1

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3D0u.png)

I do not know why this error message is showing, when I was running this in my VM single node, it was working fine. I then decided in my multinode setup to remove the `datanode1` and just run it again as a `singlenode` setup with my main computer (hostname - master), but still getting the same errors.

I hope someone could help, as I have followed other guides to setup pycharm with pyspark, but could not figure out what is going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone out there maybe able to help with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This has worked for me https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707